# Drawing a shadow in illustrator cc

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I am new to graphics design . I am struggling with some issues . I solved some issues by searing in youtube and google . I have searched about drawing a shadow but failed to find it . I know here in stack exchange there are many pro graphic designers . If you would helped me it would be so helpful for me .

See the picture below . Here is a shadow under the arrows . I would like to know that how to draw this . If anyone can say or link to some tutorials would be helpful . Thanks.

[image]

Comment: Hi M! Would it be possible to show a screenshot of what you've tried so far and what didn't work? Even if you didn't find an exact tutorial yet to reproduce this effect, you must know a few tricks already in Illustrator, enough to give it a try!

Comment: It's just an ellipse with a radial gradient.

Comment: This question is easily answered with a little practice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a lot of ways for applying this kind of shadow but but the one I prefer is this:

1. **Create a ellipse** with the help of ellipse tool of dimension let's say(W=200, H=20).
2. Now apply a **Redial Gradient** with both side black. Set the opacity of outer gradient to 0% and the another one to 40% or 50%(depends on the darker shadow you want).
3. Now **select your Gradient tool or Press G** (shortcut key) a circle will appear, align that circle similar to the ellipse you created or you can tweak to get your required shadow'

[However, Check this Video Illustration](https://youtu.be/M53p2y9zWyc)